# Best way to store and recall array of images

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uiimage, plist

I am looking for the best way to store and recall an array of images. Currently I am storing the image URLs in a `.plist` file and loading into a `collectionView` doing this in `cellForItemAt`:

```
let imageURLString = arrayOfURLsFromPlist[indexPath.row]
let imageURL = URL(string: imageURLString)
let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: imageURL!)
let image = UIImage(data: imageData!, scale: UIScreen.main.scale)
cell.image.image = image
```

This works but takes a few seconds to load. It also crashes when trying to load bigger image files. I guess thats because it hasn't loaded the image Data before I am trying to create an image from it.

What is the best way to store either the paths to an array of images or the image data in a plist and load it quickly as needed? I need to be able to load an array of images from the one `plist` file.

Apple seems to be able to load our entire camera roll instantly. How do I get that kind of performance?

**EDIT:** The url for the image is only in documents directory.

Comment: Are these URL pointing to a location on disk, or a remote location?

Comment: Sorry, good point, they are in the documents directory

Comment: If you load multiple large images you’ll crash because you run out of memory.

Comment: @matt correct, I'm looking for the best way to load the images without crashing. Would I need to create low res thumbnails?

Comment: Yes, you can use the ImageIO framework to do that.

Comment: Thanks @matt, So I could store the thumbnails alongside the url to the full size image (in a dictionary rather than array) then just show the full size image when a user selects the related thumbnail?

Comment: Definitely. Load the big image only when it is truly the big image the user needs to see. Even then you should load it only as a thumbnail at the size of the screen unless this is like Photos where the user can zoom all the way in.

Comment: You can use KingFisher library from GitHub, it is very useful. @elevate